# Making windows not appear over each other

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to check if part or an entire window is over/under another window in python?

I have two windows and I'd like to make them not appear over each other. This is in Windows, using Tkinter.

Comment: You need to obtain their bounding rectangles and do simple math of checking of rectangles intercect. But what would you do if they do inercect? Close a window? Move it (and what if the window is maximized)?

Comment: I'd move them. All I need to know is if they are covering each other, I was hoping there was a simple built in solution. Then I'd code for the behavior after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the methods `winfo_rootx` and `winfo_rooty` to get the x/y in the upper left corner.  You can use `winfo_width` and `winfo_height` to get the width and height of the window. From that it's just a little math to figure out if two windows overlap. You can then use the `geometry` method to position the windows anywhere on the screen.